# How to use cursor in a Imageswitcher with imageview

Tags: android, cursor, imageview

I'm new in Android development and I'm trying to show a list of images from my sqlite database in an ImageSwitcher. I only saved the uri something like this @drawables/photo1.

Can I create an array of fields from my `Cursor`?

This is my code:

```
public class GaleriaFotos extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;
private ImageView imgView;
private HipotecaDbAdapter dbAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;
private long id ;

//String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HipotecaDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_FOTO1));
//String uri = "R.drawable.ayto";
//private int  Idfoto = this.getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,this.getPackageName());

//private Integer[] Imgid = {Idfoto  };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galeria);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();

    if (extra == null) return;

    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    

    dbAdapter = new HipotecaDbAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.abrir();

    if (extra.containsKey(HipotecaDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_ID))
    {
       id = extra.getLong(HipotecaDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_ID);
       cursor = dbAdapter.getRegistro(id);
          }

  String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HipotecaDbAdapter.C_COLUMNA_FOTO1));
    //String uri contiene = "R.drawable.ayto";
     int  Idfoto = this.getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,this.getPackageName());
       final Integer[] Imgid = {Idfoto};
    //final Integer[] Imgid = {Idfoto };
    imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);

     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
        }
    });
}
public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {

    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount( ) {

        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}
```

}